# How to use Google Libraries API (jQuery) with Google App Engine?

Tags: jquery, python, css

I am trying to add this [jQuery Hover effect](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/) to my site. Instead of downloading jQuery I decided to use Google Libraries API for jQuery. I got a key and copied the code that goes to the header then I copied the jQuery for the hover effect but nothing is happenning. What am I doing wrong? [This is where my test page](http://ting-1.appspot.com/jquerytest) is and below is the complete code and the handler:

```
class JQueryTest(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""<html>""")
        self.response.out.write("""<head>""")
        self.response.out.write("""<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=GOOGLE LIBRARIES API KEY"></script>""")

        self.response.out.write("""<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">

$("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'}); /*Add a higher z-index value so this image stays on top*/ 
    $(this).find('img').addClass("hover").stop() /* Add class of "hover", then stop animation queue buildup*/
        .animate({
            marginTop: '-110px', /* The next 4 lines will vertically align this image */ 
            marginLeft: '-110px',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            width: '174px', /* Set new width */
            height: '174px', /* Set new height */
            padding: '20px'
        }, 200); /* this value of "200" is the speed of how fast/slow this hover animates */

    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'}); /* Set z-index back to 0 */
    $(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop()  /* Remove the "hover" class , then stop animation queue buildup*/
        .animate({
    marginTop: '0', /* Set alignment back to default */
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '0',
            left: '0',
            width: '100px', /* Set width back to default */
            height: '100px', /* Set height back to default */
            padding: '5px'
        }, 400);
});
 </script>""")

        self.response.out.write("""<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
                                    href="/stylesheets/jquery.css" /> """)
        self.response.out.write("""<title>JQuery Test</title>""")
        self.response.out.write("</head>")
        self.response.out.write("""<body>""")
        self.response.out.write("""<div class="content">""")

        self.response.out.write("""
        <ul class="thumb">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGIfcCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGIyGCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGIm1Cww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGM-dCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGM6dCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGIuGCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGLrzCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGLWlCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://ting-1.appspot.com/image?img_id=agZ0aW5nLTFyEAsSCEhvbWVQYWdlGLWlCww" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>""")

        self.response.out.write("""</div>""")
        self.response.out.write("</body></html>")
```

Comment: jQuery is loaded just fine on this page, so your problem is in your jQuery code, not anything about the Google jQuery API or Google AppEngine. When you're trying to debug Javascript, it's generally not helpful to look at your back-end code - focus on what's delivered to the browser.

Comment: Although... your code runs fine in jsFiddle, so I might have spoken too soon: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/gdsxH/

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not wrapping your jQuery code in `$(document).ready()`, so the DOM doesn't exist yet at the time you're trying to attach the handlers. In general, any time you need to reference DOM elements in the page (as opposed to just defining functions to be called later), you have to wrap it all in a `.ready()` callback so that it won't run until the DOM is completely loaded. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
            // ...
        }, function() {
            // ...
        });
});
```

That should work - it does here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/gdsxH/1/

Comment: The JS is also in the same script-tag that's loading jquery. It should be in a separate one, with no src specified.

Comment: @ nrabinowitz and Greg: Both fixes was needed to make it work. Thanks! And thanks for reference to jsfiddle, I didn't know.